# How to convert a string to a date in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular13

How to covert a string to a date in Angular13?

For example:
`str = '2022-06-09T22:00:00Z';` to a datetime `mm/dd/yyyy --:-- --`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are okay with using a library, I would recommend to use moment.js.
Here's [a link](https://momentjs.com/)!

Firstly, since we can not access the inbuilt functions from a string, we need to convert it to a date:

```js
var date = new Date("2022-06-09T22:00:00Z")
```

Using **moment.js**:

```js
moment.utc(d).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss')     // -> 06/09/2022 22:00:00
```

Using **standard in-built functions**:

```js
var formatted = ("0"+(d.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + d.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + d.getUTCFullYear() + " " + ("0" + d.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + d.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + d.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2);
```

If you don't want the time in UTC, you can simply puzzle it around to remove it.

Comment: Moment.js will be deprecated

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date("2022-06-09T22:00:00Z")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular pipe [date](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

```html
<span>{{ str | date: 'mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss' }}</span>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r8n3ef?file=src/app/app.component.html)